# How is application lifecycle managed in PHP frameworks?

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, nginx

I come from a Java background, where the JVM is a long-running process, servers can be started by user code and application state is normally kept and managed by the framework of choice (e.g. Spring).

In the PHP world, things are stateless, as each script execution is volatile in the sense that it does not keep state (unless it uses an external medium, like a DB, in-memory cache, etc). The web server invokes the script via CGI (probably through php-fpm to optimise resources).

Is it correct that every single HTTP request incurs in the overhead of initialising the framework and middleware only for that request? It appears so when reading [Laravel's Request Lifecycle](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/lifecycle), for example.

Doesn't this entail a lot of repetitive overhead for every single request that enters the system (e.g. detecting environment, initialising handlers, routes, ORM, logging, etc.)?

Or am I missing something? Do these frameworks indeed keep state in some manner?

Comment: You are correct, the entire PHP code is run from scratch each time, which includes evaluating classes and function definitions and everything else again. Opcode caches help with that somewhat, but fundamentally that's the model in which you need to think.

Comment: If I understand correctly, Opcache simply caches the compiled versions of the scripts, but it does not prevent them from being executed over and over again.

Comment: That's right, it will have to be reevaluated again, it's mostly skipping the parse step. I'm not entirely up to date with what kind of caches exist, perhaps some caches can do more than that; but that's certainly the baseline.